# .NET Ulong to binary string representation?

Tags: c#, .net

I now want to print on the screen the binary (base 2) representation of a ulong (i.e. something like 0000000000000000000000001, I know that's not enough zeroes)

I just noticed that for some reason there's no Convert.ToString(ulong, base) overload, meaning that I **can** convert a **long** into a base2 string representation, but I can't do the same with **ulong**.

Is there any other .net method to do this? Is there a reason why this method is not there? (the method is there for uint). Will casting it to a long yield the same results?

Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you could write `Convert.ToString((long)value, 2);`

Casting a `ulong` to `long` doesn't change the bit pattern at all.

As I recall, there are no `Convert` methods to deal with `UInt64` or `UInt32` because `Convert` is intended to be CLS Compliant, and public methods that deal with unsigned values aren't CLS Compliant.

See [Common Language Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3(v=vs.100).aspx).

This does not change the bit pattern. Consider:

```
ulong foo = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString((long) foo, 2));

foo = 0x8000000000000000;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString((long)foo, 2));
```

The output is:

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Note that the first line has 63 bits. The high bit is 0. The second line has 64 bits. The high bit is set correctly.

Comment: That sets the initial bit to 1 even if it's turned off, doesn't it?

Comment: @Gaspa79: I encourage you to try it and find out.

Comment: @EricLippert I tried it and that's what it seems it does, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @Gaspa79: Gan you give an example of a ulong with an off high bit which has an on high bit when converted to long?

Comment: @EricLippert No. I see what's going on. The convert method doesn't leftpad the converted string with zeroes. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Downvoter? It's customary to provide a reason for the downvote.